Non-wandering set of diffeomorphism with a unique fixed point
Let $M$ be a closed manifold and $f\in\mathrm{Diff}^\infty(M)$ be a diffeomorphism of $M$. Suppose that $f$ has a fixed point $p_0$, and that for every $p\in M$, we have $f^n(p)\rightarrow p_0$.
Can we conclude that the non-wandering set $\Omega(f)$ is just $\{p_0\}$?
I would have thought the answer was “obviously yes,” but after a bit of reflection, I couldn't think of anything actually stopping there being a point $p’$ for which nearby points can take arbitrarily long to get close to $p_0$, and in the meantime might “wrap back around” to somewhere near $p’$. On the other hand, I suspect compactness would probably force “wrapping back” to be possible only finitely many times, but I don’t see a good way to show this, especially since I don’t have a good sense of what this “wrapping back” could meaningfully look like.

There is a counter-example among homeomorphisms of the projective plane, where the non-wandering set is a projective line while there is a unique limit point. I do not see why it would be impossible for diffeomorphisms.

@MoisheKohan What is this counterexample? Do you have a reference? It’d probably be useful for helping me think about this.

Here is a counter-example for homeomorphisms of surfaces.
Start with the "standard example". Namely, let $g: (x,y)\mapsto (2x, y/2)$ be the linear map of the real plane as in that example; let $G$ be the cyclic group generated by $g$. Restrict the $G$-action to the subset $Q\subset {\mathbb R}^2$, which is the first coordinate quadrant $x\ge 0, y\ge 0$ with the origin removed. Clearly, all the orbits of the $G$-action on $Q$ are discrete and point-stabilizers are trivial. Now, form the quotient of $Q$ by the equivalence relation
$$
(x,0)\sim (0, 1/y).
$$
This quotient $A$ is homeomorphic to the open Moebius band. The 1-point compactification $P=A\cup\{\infty\}$ of $A$ is homeomorphic to the projective plane.  The map $(x,0)\mapsto (0, 1/y)$ is $G$-equivariant, hence, the $G$-action on $Q$ descends to a $G$-action on $A$. It further extends to a topological action of $G$ on $P$ that fixes the point $\infty$. It is clear that or the $G$-action on $A$ all orbits "escape to infinity", i.e.
$$
\lim_{n\to \pm\infty} g^n(p)=\infty\in P, \forall p\in P. 
$$
However, for each point $p\in A$ which is the projection of some $(x,0)\in Q$, and each neighborhood $U$ of $p$, the subset $\{n\in \mathbb N: g^n U\cap U\ne \emptyset\}$   is infinite (for the same reason that the $G$-action on $Q$ is not proper in the conventional sense). Hence, every such $p$ is a nonwandering point for the semigroup generated by the action of $g$ on $P$.
